# 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'. When migrate

Tags: python, django, geolocation, osgeo

I am building a WebApp . AND I am stuck on an Error.

**What i am trying to do**

I am making a Location Based BlogApp and I am using `PointField` in models.

**The Problem**

> 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'

This error is keep showing when i `migrate`. When i go into admin then this error is keep showing.

settings.py

This is the DataBase i am using.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '---------',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

**What have i tried**

- I also tried chaning `'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'` to `'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'`. BUT it is showing

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not open extension control file "C:/Files/PostgreSQL/13/share/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

- I also tried many answers but nothing worked for me.
- I have installed `pip install psycopg2`.

Comment: so did you install postgis extension?

Comment: I don't know Sir, How can i check it that is installed or Not ? I didn't find anywhere.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41060/installing-postgis-on-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is showing that there's no `database` in Path.

You should reinstall `postresql` and remember that select `stackbuilder` checbox to tick ok. AND you will automactically redirect to Add `Stack builders` to Path.